# Combining multiple Find and Replace functions into one

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Apps Script to run multiple find and replace functions but it doesn't seem very efficient to do it this way:

First Function looks like this:

```
    function findAndReplace1() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YouTube');
   var range = sheet.getRange('A2:D');
   var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder('&#39;');
   textFinder.replaceAllWith("");
}
```

Second function looks like this:

```
function findAndReplace2() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YouTube');
   var range = sheet.getRange('A2:D');
   var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder('|');
   textFinder.replaceAllWith(" ");
}
```

And so on.

It works OK but I would like to have just one function that performs multiple find & replace 'functions'.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function findAndReplace1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
   sh1.createTextFinder('B2').replaceAllWith("found1");
   sh1.createTextFinder('B3').replaceAllWith("found2");
}
```

Before:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |

After:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | A2 | found1 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| 3 | A3 | found2 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |

or using a forEach:

```
function findAndReplace1() {
  const arr = [{find:'B2',repl:'found1'},{find:'B3',repl:'found2'}];//add more as you desire
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  arr.forEach(obj => sh.createTextFinder(obj.find).replaceAllWith(obj.repl));
}
```